# Drawing maps based on census data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, census

I have a list of points that I want to overlay on a map of San Francisco using ggplot2.
Each point is a longitude, latitude pair.
I want the resulting map to be in a longitude/latitude coordinate system.
I managed to reproduce Hadley Wickham's [directions for plotting polygon shapefiles](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) using his example file. I am using R 2.15.1 for Windows.

However, I tried to use cdp files downloaded from the [UScensus2010cdp package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UScensus2000cdp/index.html).
Here's my code snippet:

```
require("rgdal") 
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("sp")
require("plyr")
gpclibPermit() # required for fortify method
require(UScensus2010)
require(UScensus2010cdp)
data(california.cdp10)
sf <- city(name = "san francisco", state="ca")
sf.points = fortify(sf)
```

I get the following error:

```
Using name to define regions.
Error in unionSpatialPolygons(cp, invert(polys)) : input lengths differ
In addition: Warning message:
In split(as.numeric(row.names(attr)), addNA(attr[, region], TRUE)) :
   NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does anybody know:

1. What is a good value to give to the region parameter of fortify()?
2. If that fails, a source of map data with untransformed lat/long coordinates for San Francisco that ggplot2 can draw?
3. Alternatively, I found [here](https://data.sfgov.org/Geography/San-Francisco-Shoreline-Zipped-Shapefile-Format-/kj7y-jjpu) another map of San Francisco, whose data is translated. Can you tell me how to either translate this data to raw lat/long or make the reverse translation for my set of points?

Comment: the link within the link to [UScensus2010cdp package](http://lakshmi.calit2.uci.edu/census2000/censuspackages/UScensus2010cdp_1.00.tar.gz) appears to be broken

Comment: Thanks, I edited this to point to the link you gave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## note:

- unable to access [`UScensus2010cdp`](http://lakshmi.calit2.uci.edu/census2000/censuspackages/UScensus2010cdp_1.00.tar.gz), so am using [`UScensus2000cpd`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UScensus2000cdp/index.html) which replicates the error.

## The issue

The issue arises from the fact that `fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` relies on converting the `row.names` to numeric, and the rownames of your data are the identifiers.

```
ggplot2:::fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 

function (model, data, region = NULL, ...) 
{
    attr <- as.data.frame(model)
    if (is.null(region)) {
        region <- names(attr)[1]
        message("Using ", region, " to define regions.")
    }
    polys <- split(as.numeric(row.names(attr)), addNA(attr[, 
        region], TRUE))
    cp <- polygons(model)
    try_require(c("gpclib", "maptools"))
    unioned <- unionSpatialPolygons(cp, invert(polys))
    coords <- fortify(unioned)
    coords$order <- 1:nrow(coords)
    coords
}
```

In your case

```
row.names(sf@data)
## [1] "california_586" "california_590" "california_616"
```

are the identifiers you wish to use as the region parameters, as `place` `state` and `name` do not uniquely identify the three polygons.

```
# as.character used to coerce from factor
lapply(lapply(sf@data[,c('place','state','name')], unique), as.character)
## $place
## [1] "67000"
## 
## $state
## [1] "06"
## 
## $name
## [1] "San Francisco"
```

As a character vector where the elements begin with alphabetic characters, when coerced to numeric, it becomes `NA`

```
as.numeric(rownames(sf@data))
## [1] NA NA NA
## Warning message:
## NAs introduced by coercion
```

Which is one of the warnings given

## Solution

1. Define a column to be the rownames
2. Set the row.names to `NULL` or `1:nrow(sf@data)`

So..

```
# rownames
sf@data[['place_id']] <- rownames(sf@data)
row.names(sf@data) <- NULL

# fortify
sf_ggplot <- fortify(sf, region = 'place_id')
# merge to add the original data
sf_ggplot_all <- merge(sf_ggplot, sf@data, by.x = 'id', by.y = 'place_id')
# very basic and uninteresting plot
ggplot(sf_ggplot_all,aes(x=long,y=lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill =pop2000)) + 
  coord_map()
```

[image]